# Find the domain of convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I need to find the domain of convergence of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{5^n}{4^n}}{n^x + \vert x \vert ^n} = f_n(x)$$

I've managed to find it for $0\le x$ by using the ratio test, in short:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)} = ... =\frac{5}{4} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^x + \vert x \vert ^n}{(n+1)^x + \vert x\vert^{n+1}}$$

I divided the problem to 4 cases:

case 1: $x>1$

case 2: $0\le x\le1$

case 3: $-1\le x\lt0$

case 4: $-1>x$

I've got that for $x>\frac{5}{4}$ the series converges and for $0\le x\le\frac{5}{4}$ the series diverges (cases 1 and 2).

Now my problem is when I'm tring to find convergence\divergence where $-1\le x < 0$.

Using the basic methods I'm getting $\frac{5}{4} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{0}{0}$.

I tried to use L'Hôpital's rule (3 times) and the expression just getting longer with no way out.

Maybe I missed something or did something wrong?

Thanks!